# bully can't work on mon0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, alfa-wireless

I'm running bully on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I got this output:

```
educ@educ-TOSHIBA-NB500:~$ sudo apt-get install libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libssl-dev 
[sudo] password for educ: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libnl-3-dev is already the newest version.
libnl-genl-3-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
educ@educ-TOSHIBA-NB500:~$ sudo bully mon1 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -c 8 -v 3 -C -F -l61
Unable to get hardware MAC address for 'mon1'
Please specify --source for the interface
educ@educ-TOSHIBA-NB500:~$ sudo airmon-ng


Interface    Chipset        Driver

wlan3        Ralink RT2870/3070    rt2800usb - [phy1]
wlan0        Unknown     rtl8192ce - [phy0]

educ@educ-TOSHIBA-NB500:~$ sudo airmon-ng start wlan3


Found 3 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
-e 
PID    Name
674    NetworkManager
842    wpa_supplicant
2213    dhclient
Process with PID 2213 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0


Interface    Chipset        Driver

wlan3        Ralink RT2870/3070    rt2800usb - [phy1]
                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
wlan0        Unknown     rtl8192ce - [phy0]

educ@educ-TOSHIBA-NB500:~$ 

educ@educ-TOSHIBA-NB500:~$ sudo bully mon0 -b  XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  -c 8 -v 3 -C -F -l61
[!] Bully v1.0-22 - WPS vulnerability assessment utility
[+] Switching interface 'mon0' to channel '8'
[!] ioctl(SIOCSIWFREQ) on 'mon0' failed with '-1'
[X] Unable to set channel on 'mon0', exiting
educ@educ-TOSHIBA-NB500:~$
```

When I run sudo airodump-ng mon0, it works fine.

What does this error message mean?

I didn't have that problem with bully on Ubuntu 12.10 LTS until i upgrade it to 14.04 What can i do to solve that problem?

any help would be appreciated

Comment: There's 5 commands run there, what is the error you're concerned about? And if it's the 2nd (?) one, did you *"specify --source for the interface"* like it tells you?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/ifplugd
```

Then put this line in the file:

```
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES=""
```

Save it and you are good to go!

That's it, problem was: your device is busy.
Found in http://blog.flowl.info/2014/wlan-problem-device-resource-busy-solution/